# Is it possible to skew HTML element by a number of pixels using CSS transform?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

My problem is:
there's a block containing variable number of HTML elements. Something like this...

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
</ul>
```

This block must have a skew on the right side (the content must not be skewed). The horizontal size of this skew must be fixed. So adding CSS rules like...

```
.list {
  position: relative;
  background: #A0A0FF;
}
.list:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -10px;
  width: 20px;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  background: #A0A0FF;
}
```

...won't do because in this case the skew will have variable horizontal size depending on the number of items in the list. The only solution that comes to my mind is to calculate the number of degrees in js. But this is kinda meh.
So my question is: is it possible to somehow skew an element by a number of pixels instead of degrees/radians using CSS?

Comment: That CSS *does* skew the `.list:after` pseudo-element -- but of course, the content of that element is just a space, so you may not be able to see that it does...

Comment: No...`skew` requires an "angle" value. - [**Skew @ MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#skew)

Comment: Do you have an image of what this is supposed to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve the same `skew` appearance by using a linear gradient on a pseudo-element.

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  width: 200px;
  background: #663399;
  margin: 25px auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}
ul::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #663399 0%, #663399 50%, transparent 50%, transparent 100%);
  width: 16px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if my message is irrelevant to this exact case, but once I searched for **"CSS skew in pixels"** and although neither this question is about what I tried to find *(provide the exact width in px to skew)*, nor the accepted answer solves my problem, I still believe this can help someone someday.

As we know, `transform: skew()` receives only angles as a parameter.
In order to get the exact width when the angle is unknown, one should calculate the angle using arctangent. Luckily, JavaScript 1.0 `Math` provides [atan2()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan2) method to return the arctangent (in radians) by given X and Y coordinates.

Thus, calculating the skew angle has the solution on JS.
[The example below](https://jsfiddle.net/pLne9t84/) draws diagonal lines (via `border-bottom`/`border-left`) based on the dimensions of the underlying elements.

```js
let prevY = null;
document.querySelectorAll('.a').forEach(el => {
    const top = el.style.top;
    const left = el.style.left;
    const width = el.style.width;
    const height = el.style.height;
    const xEl = document.querySelector('#x' + el.id.substr(1));

    xEl.style.top = top;
    xEl.style.left = left;
    xEl.style.width = width;
    xEl.style.height = height;

    applySkew(el);
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
    prevY = null;
    document.querySelectorAll('.a').forEach(el => {
        applySkew(el);
    });
});
function applySkew(el) {
    const xEl = document.querySelector('#x' + el.id.substr(1));
    const top = el.style.top;
    const w = el.offsetWidth;
    const h = el.offsetHeight;
    const directionUp = prevY && prevY != top;
    prevY = top;
    if(w < h) {
        xEl.style.borderBottom = 'none';
        xEl.style.borderLeft = 'black 1px solid';
        xEl.style.transform = 'skewX(' + Math.atan2((directionUp ? -1 : 1) * w, h) + 'rad) translateX(' + (w / 2) + 'px)';
    } else {
        xEl.style.borderLeft = 'none';
        xEl.style.borderBottom = 'black 1px solid';
        xEl.style.transform = 'skewY(' + Math.atan2((directionUp ? -1 : 1) * h, w) + 'rad) translateY(-' + (h / 2) + 'px)';
    }
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body > div {
    margin: 5% 0 0 5%;
    background: yellow;
    position: relative;
    height: 40%;
    width: 90%;
}
body > div > div {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
&nbsp;
<div>
    <div id="a0" class="a" style="
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 7.5%;
        height: 70%;
        background-color: rgba(0,255,255,.5);
    "></div>
    <div id="a1" class="a" style="
        top: 40%;
        left: 7.5%;
        width: 17.5%;
        height: 30%;
        background-color: rgba(0,255,255,.2);
    "></div>
    <div id="a2" class="a" style="
        top: 40%;
        left: 25%;
        width: 37%;
        height: 55%;
        background-color: rgba(0,255,255,.4);
    "></div>
    <div id="a3" class="a" style="
        top: 25%;
        left: 62%;
        width: 3%;
        height: 70%;
        background-color: rgba(0,255,255,.1);
    "></div>
    <div id="a4" class="a" style="
        top: 25%;
        left: 65%;
        width: 35%;
        height: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(0,255,255,.6);
    "></div>
    <div id="x0"></div>
    <div id="x1"></div>
    <div id="x2"></div>
    <div id="x3"></div>
    <div id="x4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are after, But is this what you are searching for?

```css
.list {
  position: relative;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.list:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
  width: 20px;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
  <li class="item">...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No. I need a skew with a fixed horizontal size. And as I wrote in my post such CSS as you posted will result in a skew with variable horizontal size because the number of elements in the list in my case is variable.